# упорядочить список на основе класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, list

Создан список, в каждом узле которого несколько компонентов информации. Нужно упорядочить список по одному из элементов. Например, по Фио или возрасту. Не важно, по убыванию или по возрастанию. Не совсем понятно как вычленить именно один элемент, для которого нужно провести сортировку списка. Надеюсь на помощь, так как сама еще новичок.

```
 class CLERKnode{ //узел в списке
 string clerkName;
int age;
string position;
int WorkExperience; 

 class CLERKnode* next; // указатель на следующий елемент
    
};
```

Comment: А как вы вообще сортируете список? Скажем, список целых чисел? Где-то же происходит сравнение значений двух элементов списка? Вот в этом месте и  сравнивайте нужные поля элементов.

Comment: Спасибо, дальше по коду сортировки нигде не было сортировки. учту

Comment: Тут пример есть https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort.

Comment: @tocic У автора вопроса список, писанный вручную, так что вряд ли он сможет использовать стандартный алгоритм... Тогда было бы проще всего просто использовать пользовательский компаратор.

Comment: @Harry можно написать итератор свой и begin/end, если нужен именно такой список. Тогда сможет использовать.

Comment: @tocic Да, но большое у меня подозрение — судя по вопросу — что он этим будет заниматься...